# Why getComputedStyle returns 'auto' for slider's width after page-reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here a link: [wbrapist.github.io/slider/index.html](https://wbrapist.github.io/slider/index.html)

First time when you loading page, it's fine (getComputedStyle returns valid value). But just try to reload page by Ctrl+F5, wait for a few seconds then just reload by F5 and you'll see that navigation of slider not at center position. In this moment you can open the browser's console and see that getComputedStyle after reload (F5) returns just 'auto' value. Why is this happening? Why after force reload (ctrl+f5) it's okay and in otherwise case is not?

Can notice: in that case my slider's switch slides animation is not working too. (there getting values via getComputedStyle() too)

Here a bit of code:

```js
var sliderWidth      = getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0]).width;

function setSliderNavPosition() {
  var nav = document.querySelector('.slider .navigation');
  var navWidth = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(nav).width);
  var slidersWidth = parseFloat(sliderWidth);

  nav.style.left = ( (slidersWidth / 2) - (navWidth / 2) ) + 'px';
}
```

This trouble exist in Chrome and Mozilla at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use the document when it's not fully loaded. Depending on the time it takes to load it, your values are going to be different. That's why you get different behaviors.

To solve this, just wait for the document to be loaded by wrapping your code like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    /* ...YOUR CODE GOES HERE... */
});
```

Comment: Thanks ya!
I hear about this event, but I thought that 'defer' attribute of 'script' tag is the same.

Comment: @DmitryFateev When you load a page, 2 main events are fired: `DOMContentLoaded`, when the DOM is ready (All the HTML is loaded). Then, a `load` event fires when all external resources (CSS, images) are loaded. Using `defer` waits for the first event to fire, but not the other one. In your case, I think it is the CSS that was causing a problem. It was not loaded yet.